# Terminal: Line going invisible after line break

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2

See [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nExCu.png).

After the first line hits end of the terminal and the cursor/text goes into the second line the first line goes invisible and the second takes it's place.

The first line will still be executed and I am still able to go back and edit the now invisible text.

Comment: try a different theme with your zsh?  I expect its an error with your PS Variables;  please show your PS1; echo $PS1

Comment: I found the answer, @CalvinTaylor you reminded me that I turned off locale variables, which was the reason for this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, turning off "Set locale variables automatically" was the reason.

It can be set in the Preferences > Profiles > Terminal Tab > Environment.